# Laravel 8 password.confirm feature not working giving a route not found error

Tags: php, laravel

I know this question is bit general, but I am trying to use the `password.confirm` middleware in some of my routes which I need to be secured.

I've checked the Laravel blogs page [here](https://laravel-news.com/new-password-confirmation-in-laravel-6-2) and it says I should be able to just add `middleware('password.confirm')` and it should work directly.
However, when I do this I just get an error `Route['password.confirm'] not found`.

Am I missing something in the Laravel config?
I am currently using Laravel 8.32 with PHP v7.3

This is what my route looks like in `web.php`.

```php
Route::get('/modifyInstitutes', [ModifyInstitutesController::class, 'index'])
->name('modifyInstitutes')
->middleware('password.confirm')
```

Here is my view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="flex justify-center">

    <div class="w-10/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
        <h1 class="mb-8 text-3xl text-center">{{ __('lang.modifyInstitute') }}</h1>
        @if (session('instituteUpdatePass'))
            <div id="userUpdateStatus" class="bg-green-500 p-4 rounded-lg mb-6 text-white text-center">
                {{ session('instituteUpdatePass')  }}
            </div>
        @endif
        @if (session('instituteUpdateFail'))
            <div id="userUpdateStatus" class="bg-red-500 p-4 rounded-lg mb-6 text-white text-center">
                {{ session('instituteUpdateFail') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        @if(auth()->user()->getUserRoleName()->name == Config::get('constants.user_roles.super_user'))
            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">{{ __('lang.institutionName') }}</th>
                        <th scope="col">{{ __('lang.instituteDescription') }}</th>
                        <th scope="col">{{ __('lang.email') }}</th>
                        <th scope="col">{{ __('lang.phoneNumber') }}</th>
                        <th scope="col">{{ __('lang.modifyInstitute') }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($institutions as $institute)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $institute->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $institute->description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $institute->email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $institute->phone }} </td>
                            <td><button class="button-manage btn-sm ml-4 mb-2" style="border:none;" data-instituteid="{{ $institute->id_institutions }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i> </button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="instituteEditModal{{ $institute->id_institutions }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{__('lang.modifyInstitute')}}</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{{ url('/modifyInstitutes') }}" id="modifyInstitutes" method="post">
                                            @csrf
                                            <input type="hidden" id="instituteId{{ $institute->id_institutions }}" name="institute_id" value="{{ $institute->id_institutions }}">
                                            <div class="mb-4">
                                                <label for="institute_name" class="sr-only"> {{ __('lang.institutionName') }}</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="institute_name" id="instituteName{{ $institute->id_institutions }}" placeholder="{{ __('lang.institutionName') }}" class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-2 rounded-lg @error('institute_name') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('institute_name') }}">

                                                @error('institute_name')
                                                <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                                                    {{ $message }}
                                                </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mb-4">
                                                <label for="description" class="sr-only"> {{ __('lang.description') }}</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="description" id="description{{ $institute->id_institutions }}" placeholder="{{ __('lang.description') }}" class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-2 rounded-lg @error('description') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('description') }}">

                                                @error('description')
                                                <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                                                    {{ $message }}
                                                </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mb-4">
                                                <label for="email" class="sr-only"> {{ __('lang.email') }}</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email{{ $institute->id_institutions }}" placeholder="{{ __('lang.email') }}" class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-2 rounded-lg @error('email') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                                @error('email')
                                                <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                                                    {{ $message }}
                                                </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mb-4">
                                                <label for="phone" class="sr-only">{{ __('lang.phoneNumber') }}</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phoneNumber{{ $institute->id_institutions }}" placeholder="{{ __('lang.phoneNumber') }}" class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-2 rounded-lg @error('phone') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('phone') }}">

                                                @error('phone')
                                                <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                                                    {{ $message }}
                                                </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mb-4">
                                                <label for="comment" class="sr-only">{{ __('lang.comment') }}</label>
                                                <textarea name="comment" id="comment{{ $institute->id_institutions }}" placeholder="{{ __('lang.comment') }}" class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-2 rounded-lg @error('comment') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('comment') }}"></textarea>
                                                @error('comment')
                                                <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                                                    {{ $message }}
                                                </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <button type="submit" class="bg-green-400 text-white px-4 py-3 rounded font-medium w-full">{{ __('lang.modifyInstitute') }}</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                {!! $institutions->links() !!}
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>

</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/modifyInstitutes.js') }}"></script>
 @endsection
```

And In my controller I have the index method being used like this

```
class ModifyInstitutesController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware(['auth']);
  }

  public function index()
  {
     $institutionRecords = Institutions::paginate(10);

     return view('institutes.manageInstitutes', ['institutions' => 
     $institutionRecords ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding it in particular? It sounds like you aren't doing it properly.  
Can you show us the route from the web.php file? Also, can you show us where you are calling the route?

Comment: You'll need to write something like `Route::get('/my-route')->middleware('password.confirm')`.

Comment: @JustCarty Yes I am doing that exactly,  here is my example Route::get('/modifyInstitutes', [ModifyInstitutesController::class, 'index'])->name('modifyInstitutes')->middleware('password.confirm')

Comment: In that case, it's the view that is causing the issue. The error appears as though you are calling `route('password.confirm')`.

Comment: @JustCarty can you suggest a solution on how should I describe my route, I have even tried adding the middleware inside the ModifyInstitutesController like `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'password_confirm']);
    }` but I am getting the same error

Comment: It's in the view, not the route. Update your question with where this route is called (show us the entire view).

Comment: @JustCarty, I have made the edit to show my view and my Controller

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are calling this route somewhere like `route('password.confirm')` but that should be `route('modifyInstitutes')`